# Python, quitting matplotlib FuncAmination() when animation is fed by incoming sensor data

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

I am getting data to a Raspberry Pi from some sensors. 
Once the animation starts, I have not found a way to get it to stop the animation and then execute the rest of the code in the program.
I have tried quit() and animation.event_source.stop() to no avail. I read the documentation and it looks like the method animation.FuncAnimation() is some sort of loop that calls animate() and never ends in my case. Here are a few versions of my code below. Nothing changes between version below the commented out line.

```
from gpiozero import MCP3008
from timeit import default_timer
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

# This is specific to the ADC I am using for my sensor
ch2 = MCP3008(2)
vals = []
timer = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

#this is the fuction used as a parameter for the animation.FuncAnimation
def animate(i):
    timer.append(default_timer())
    vals.append(ch2.value)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(timer,vals)
#______________________________________
try:
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 50)
    plt.show()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    plt.close("all")
    #The plot created below is for saving the final set of collected data
    plt.plot(timer,vals)
    plt.xlabel("Time(s)")
    plt.ylabel("V")
    plt.savefig('/home/pi/programs/pics/plot.jpg')
    plt.close('all')
    quit()
```

The idea was that you would press control c, then the rest of the code would execute and the program would end, but the animation keeps running until I keyboard interrupt multiple times, and the rest of the code(under except) never runs. I have also tried...

```
from gpiozero import MCP3008
from timeit import default_timer
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

# This is specific to the ADC I am using for my sensor
ch2 = MCP3008(2)
vals = []
timer = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

#this is the fuction used as a parameter for the animation.FuncAnimation
def animate(i):
    timer.append(default_timer())
    vals.append(ch2.value)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(timer,vals)
#______________________________________
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 50)
plt.show()
commmand = input('Type q and press enter to quit')

if commmand == 'q':
    plt.close("all")
    #The plot created below is for saving the final set of collected data
    plt.plot(timer,vals)
    plt.xlabel("Time(s)")
    plt.ylabel("V")
    plt.savefig('/home/pi/programs/pics/plot.jpg')
    plt.close('all')
    quit()
```

I also tried putting print statements in various places after the plt.show after the line where ani is assigned, and the code never gets past that point.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code after `plt.show()` will only execute, once the window that is shown is closed. At that point you do not have the figure available in pyplot to use `plt.savefig` any more. However, you may very well create a new plot, like you're doing already in the code and the second version of the code should run fine once you close the matplotlib window.

```
#from gpiozero import MCP3008 # not available here
from timeit import default_timer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# emulate sensor
class MCP3008():
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.x = 0.5
        self.r = r
    def value(self):
        self.x = self.r*self.x*(1.-self.x)
        return self.x
ch2 = MCP3008(3.62)
vals = []
timer = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

#this is the fuction used as a parameter for the animation.FuncAnimation
def animate(i):
    timer.append(default_timer())
    vals.append(ch2.value())
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(timer,vals, marker=".", ls="")

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 50)
plt.show()

plt.close("all")
#The plot created below is for saving the final set of collected data
plt.plot(timer,vals)
plt.xlabel("Time(s)")
plt.ylabel("V")
plt.savefig('plot.jpg')
plt.close('all')
```

If you want to keep the plot open and save the plot upon a key press, the following would be an option. It saves the actualy plot in the state when the `q` key is pressed. (Also, the axes is not cleared every iteration, but only the line data is updated, just to show that approach).

```
#from gpiozero import MCP3008 # not available here
from timeit import default_timer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# emulate sensor
class MCP3008():
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.x = 0.5
        self.r = r
    def value(self):
        self.x = self.r*self.x*(1.-self.x)
        return self.x
ch2 = MCP3008(3.62)
vals = []
timer = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
line, = ax1.plot([],[], marker=".", ls="")
ax1.set_xlabel("Time(s)")
ax1.set_ylabel("V")

#this is the fuction used as a parameter for the animation.FuncAnimation
def animate(i):
    timer.append(default_timer())
    vals.append(ch2.value())
    line.set_data(timer,vals)
    ax1.relim()
    ax1.autoscale_view()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 50)

def press(event):
    if event.key == 'q':
        ani.event_source.stop()
        fig.savefig("plot.png")
        print("Plot saved")

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for posting. I tried your second block of code and the animation does not show up unless I put a line plt.show() after the where ani is assigned. When I put in the plt show, I ran into the same problem as before. Does the code as is work on your computer? I am from the terminal in Raspbian on a pi (a linux os).

Comment: Yes both codes run as they are (for that reason I emulated the MCP3008 part, such that the code can be copied and pasted). It's clear that if `plt.show` is not at the very end but some place before, the required saving will not happen. I do not know why it wouldn't work for you though. Does the first version at least run as expected?

Comment: Got it to work! Thanks! I needed plt.show() last or it would cut the program off. Thanks so much!

Comment: I feel like that is what I tried to convince you of right from the beginning. Anyways, glad it works now.